# How to prevent a UDP-based channel from turning into a "backdoor"?

Tags: security, sockets, networking, udp, embedded

Recently some router devices are found to contain backdoors, [some of which](http://www.devttys0.com/2013/10/from-china-with-love/) can be exploited with a single UDP packet. I realize that some of these backdoors are not necessarily malicious, as I have done the same thing in my own products for troubleshooting purposes: open a socket to send heartbeat packets to the server, and listen for commands (such as 'ping') from the server. Some commands can actually execute arbitrary code on the device, making my heart pound like a drum...

My question is, as a primitive form of authentication, if I compare the remote **address and port** of the UDP packets received with the actual **address and port** of the server that the socket is sending packets to, will things be safe enough (i.e., no attack can be exploited)? The sample code is as follows:

```
if ((bytes = recvfrom(sock, buf, sizeof(buf) - 1, 0, 
                      (sockaddr *)addr, addrlen)) == -1)
{
    perror("recvfrom");
    return -1;
}

buf[bytes] = '\0';
printf("%s: received: %s\n", __func__, buf);

if (addrcmp(addr, (sockaddr_in *)ai_server->ai_addr) == 0)
{
    // do things
}
```

Code for addrcmp():

```
int addrcmp(sockaddr_in *a1, sockaddr_in *a2)
{
    if (a1->sin_addr.s_addr == a2->sin_addr.s_addr &&
        a1->sin_port == a2->sin_port)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I do not understand - how could you receive any packets on an end point that are not destined for that end point?

Comment: @MarkMennell What I want to ensure is the commands I receive are actually originated from the server I'm talking to, so I would compare the address and port of the sender with the server's address and port, to make sure the sender is actually the server itself. But as Rajesh pointed out, it's easy to spoof the address and port.

Comment: I see you meant comparing it against a known address rather than the address it was received on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you ensure that the packet is received from the address that you are talking to, it need not be the machine you are talking to. It is easy to spoof the address and port. Verifying the sender's address/port is a first of many steps you could take
- If you are talking to some well known port and if someone can guess the address, they can still send a packet with correct address and port. So, you could explore using ephemeral ports on one side
- If you choose to use ephemeral ports, then the attacker can still guess the port as there are only 64K ports. So, you could move to TCP. This would make the attacker guess the sequence number as well. This too was broken in some cases

IMO, you should design the system assuming the attacker knows the connection details. The man-in-the-middle knows your connection details anyway. You could try some of the following
- validate the fields in the packet before it is accepted. Make sure the inputs in various fields in the packet are within acceptable limits
- authenticate the content. Use something to sign the data
- encrypt and authenticate the connection

If it is something like heartbeat for management purpose and if this need not go over internet, you should consider completely isolating the management network from data ports. In that case, you could probably avoid some of the checks listed above.

This list is not exhaustive. Most commercial products will do all these and much more and are still vulnerable.

Answer (score 1):

Your program is effectively a small firewall. You can use a firewall in front of the device to block *all* UDP traffic to the port and on the interface in concern. If your server happened to use the same port and interface can you change it?

Comment: I don't want to block all UDP traffic because I would still like to be able to query information from the device via this UDP port, or even control the device in some way. Now I've learned the concept of "ip spoofing", I think some form of encryption and authentication is the way to go.

Comment: Yes, but you can block to a specific port and interface - not all UDP traffic just the traffic the exploit is on.

Answer (score 1):

**You can't do this safely in UDP.** You shouldn't be doing this at all - it **will** be discovered and used maliciously.  Most device designers use serial console pins on the board for this, if they do it at all beyond the prototype stage.  At least that requires physical access to the device.

If you must have a remote control connection, go with something well proven.  SSH, for example, or an SSL-encrypted TCP or HTTP connection.

Comment: You mean even if I add encryption to the UDP connection, it still won't be safe? I think UDP has some nice features in my use case, such as low overhead and connectionless, which is quite suitable for heartbeat, simple request-response, and stuff.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.  for example, how are you going to prevent someone from extracting the key from the device and using it to send malicious commands?  TCP+SSL or HTTP+SSL solved these issues years ago and have been well-proven in the field.  You're designing something based on a model best known for its weaknesses.  Sometimes, everybody else really does know better. :-)

Comment: Actually the initial motivation of my design is to implement something similar to STUN which enables NAT traversal. The classical STUN is based on UDP: the server and clients communicate through UDP channel, without encryption. Later I added control commands to the channel, and that's where things go "weak", I guess.